# How do I use the same modal for add and edit in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, modal-dialog

I am noew to redux. I am working on an ecommerce application and I want to use the same modal box for both add and edit of the categories using redux but I dont know how to go about it

The code is to long for me to post here

I created a codesandbox where I uploaded my code.

this is the link below

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-microservice-u7bum

how do I achieve this

Thank you

Comment: your codesandbox link does not open any modal

Comment: Let check check it again @monesul haque